# Replacing unibody MacBook trackpad contact

Tags: macbook-pro, contacts, trackpad

The trackpad for my 2010 MacBook works perfectly except the small, round, metal contact push spring that registers clicks is sprung. Tightening the screw underneath the trackpad fixes it but, as it is tightened, there is less margin to click. Does anyone know if I can find a push contact anywhere? I've tried searching online but without result. Perhaps it because I don't know the element's technical name. Any information is helpful. Thank you.

I'm looking for something like this (http://hongjusilicon.manufacturer.globalsources.com/si/6008849837334/pdtl/Silicone-keypad/1130112657/Rubber-push-button-switch.htm).

Comment: Do you mean this?  [Touchpad Trackpad Screw For MacBook Pro Unibody](http://amzn.to/2AVyfjI)

Comment: @Allan I'm actually looking for a replacement switch. It's the silicon/rubber button that is pushed when the trackpad is clicked. The current one seems to have suffered from corrosion and no longer clicks with the feedback it should.

Comment: There’s no such thing as a unibody 2010 MacBook. The only unibody MacBook was the late 2008 model, and then the Retina range from 2015 — all others are MacBook Airs or MacBook Pros, which are not MacBooks.

Comment: @mikeScott There actually is a mid 2010 unibody MacBook. MacBooks 6,1 (late 2009)  and 7,1 (mid 2010) are both unibody.

Comment: @www139 Those models are in polycarbonate cases. They may technically be unibody, but the term is generally used to refer to an aluminium unibody case.